'DeferredAttribute' object has no attribute
im newbie in django..
i dont know why it's raise an error
its models.py codes
class PublishManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(status=Post.Status.Draft)


# Create your models here.
# First Model
class Post(models.Model):
    class Status(models.TextChoices):
        Draft = 'Dr', "Draft"
        Released = 'RL', "Released"
        Rejected = 'RJ', "Rejected"

    # Managers
    objects = models.Manager()
    Publishedss = PublishManager()

    # Author
    Author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="up")
    # information
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=9000)
    Slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250)
    # Timing
    published = models.DateTimeField(timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    Updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    # Status
    Status = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=Status.choices, default=Status.Draft)

    # Sorting
    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-published"]
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['-published'])
        ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


raise an error
and it's detail codes
def post_detail(request, id):
    print(id)
    posts1 = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id, status=Post.Status.Draft)

    context = {
        "Post": posts1
    }
    return render(request, "blog/detail.html", context)


AttributeError at /blog/post/1
'DeferredAttribute' object has no attribute 'Draft'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/post/1
Django Version: 5.0.4
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:
'DeferredAttribute' object has no attribute 'Draft'
Exception Location: D:\Python\Python\Projects\project1\blog\views.py, line 24, in post_detail
Raised during:  blog.views.post_detail
Python Executable:  D:\Python\Python\Projects\project1\venv\bin\python.exe
Python Version: 3.11.7
Python Path:
['D:\Python\Python\Projects\project1',
'C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm '
'2023.3.5\plugins\python\helpers\pycharm',
'D:\Python\Python\Projects\project1',
'C:\msys64\ucrt64\lib\python311.zip',
'C:\msys64\ucrt64\lib\python3.11',
'C:\msys64\ucrt64\lib\python3.11\lib-dynload',
'D:\Python\Python\Projects\project1\venv\lib\python3.11\site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 25 Apr 2024 08:14:02 +0000

rename the Status to status.

Typo: class Status(models.TextChoices): and Status = models.CharField(...) are declared in the same scope with the same name. Rename one of them, conventionally attributes should be written in snake case so rename the CharField.
